# Is It Safe to Unmount Disk 1 Debian Linux From Disk 0 Windows 7

Tags: windows, linux, disk-management

**Background:**

- I have an Asus P67 Sabertooth motherboard. The motherboard supports 6GB SATA.
- I have two 1TB Western Digital Caviar Black 64MB Cache SATA Drives.
- I have a Plextor PX-880SA CD/DVD Optical SATA.

Both hard drives are on the 6GB Channels.

I DO NOT dual boot ... I simply use the uEFI BIOS quick key to access drive selection on POST to determine which drive ~ OS I want to use. In Linux, I have disabled OS prober in Grub ... so if I run update-grub it won't try to wipe out my Windows MBR on disk 0.

Disk 0 is Windows 7.
Disk 1 is my Debian 6.

==================================================================================

1. Disk 0: Online

   > Vol C = Sys Reserved for W7 = 100MB NTFS
   >   Vol C = W7 (C:) = 244GB NTFS
   >   Vol D = Data (D:) = 342 GB NTFS
   >   346GB = Unallocated
2. Disk 1: Online

   > (/boot / /etc /home) = 500GB
   >   346GB = Unallocated
3. CD-ROM 0 :

   > DVD (E:)

==================================================================================

When I start Windows 7 I can see Disk 1 as 'Active' which ... concerns me ... I don't want Windows to have any access to this disk. I want to Disk 0 and Disk 1 completely separate.

**Is it safe to unmount my Linux drive from Windows 7 using diskpart? Is this even necessary to achieve my goal?**

Answer (score 0):

Windows defaults to mounting every disk that it can; as on disk1 it can not find any partitions that it can read you can safely remove it. However, there should be no problems with windows "accessing" the disk.